# BeanIo can't read special caracters

Tags: java, unix, encoding, character-encoding, bean-io

I have a .txt file with ANSI (windows-1252) Encoding i'am able to read it on windows but not on unix.

here is the xml mapping file :

> ```
>   <beanio>
>     <stream name="empData" format="csv">
>         <parser>
>             <property name="delimiter" value=";"/>
>             <property name="alwaysQuote" value="false"/>
>             <!--<property name="quote" value='' />-->
>         </parser>    
>
>             <record name="emp" class="com.MyClass" >
>             <field name="name" />
>             <field name="job" />
>             <field name="adress"/>  
>        </record>
>     </stream>
> </beanio>
> ```

Java Side :

```
StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();

    InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("mapping.xml");

    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("countries.txt"));
    factory.load(in);

    BeanReader beanReader = factory.createReader("empData", reader);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    /*Object bean =new Object();*/
    Object record = null;
    while ((record = beanReader.read()) != null) {
        System.out.println(beanReader.getRecordName() + ": "
                +((MyClass)record).getCountry());
    }
```

Result :
line : France

line : S??o Paulo   should be (São Paulo)   windows OK but unix is KO

line : USA

line : China

Any idea ?

FYI : i already tried to set Charset to UTF-8  java side .

```
new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("clearings.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but... if you have a ANSI file a.k.a. `ISO-8859-1`, you have to set the `InputStreamReader` charset as ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8.

```java
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("clearings.txt"), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```